# How to wrap each iteration in $each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, loops

I'm looping through a JSON array using the jQuery `$each` function. I think i'm being incredibly thick here, but I'd like to wrap the 3 elements in a container div on each iteration. Please advise?

```
success: function(data) {
  var access = data.query.results.json.data;
  $.each(access, function(index, value) {
    var ob = value;
    $(".front-page .main .object").append('<img class="post-image" src="' + ob.images.standard_resolution.url + '">');
    $(".front-page .main .object").append('<div class="post-caption">' + ob.caption.text + '"</div>');
    $(".front-page .main .object").append('<div class="post-tags">' + ob.tags + '"</div>');
  });
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you can create the wrapper object, append the three items to it, then append the wrapper to the target, something like this:

```js
var access = data.query.results.json.data.forEach(function(obj) {
  var $wrapper = $('<div />').appendTo('.front-page .main .object');  
  $wrapper.append(`<img class="post-image" src="${obj.images.standard_resolution.url}" />
    <div class="post-caption">${obj.caption.text}</div>
    <div class="post-tags">${obj.tags}</div>`);
});
```